# How to set the ACL to publicRead with PredefinedAcl function?

Tags: go, google-cloud-storage

```
if res, err := service.Objects.Insert(*bucketName, object).Media(file).Do(); err == nil {
     fmt.Printf("Created object %v at location %v\n\n", res.Name, res.SelfLink)
} else {
     fatalf(service, "Objects.Insert failed: %v", err)
}
```

I want to modify this code to set the ACL to publicRead, I have noticed there is a function in the API `func (*ObjectsInsertCall) PredefinedAcl` but I can't find how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by [what i found in the docs](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/storage/v1#ObjectsInsertCall.PredefinedAcl), it looks like this would do it...

```
if res, err := service.Objects.Insert(*bucketName, object).Media(file).PredefinedAcl("publicRead").Do(); err == nil {
    fmt.Printf("Created object %v at location %v\n\n", res.Name, res.SelfLink)
} else {
    fatalf(service, "Objects.Insert failed: %v", err)
}
```

(Inserted it right before the `Do()` call.) HTH, YMMV, etc.